# How to combine two features (two minimum distance classifiers)

Tags: image, matlab, object, classification, feature-selection

Hello All with my first post here,

I work on tracking objects through images without prior training. I use two features, the color of the region (the ab channels of the Lab space) and the HOG. In my initial experiments, I found that using min. distance classifier with the HOG feature alone has the advantage of low false positives FP but with high FN. On the other hand, using the min. distance classifier with the color alone increases the TP and decreases the FN results but with the price of increasing FP.

My question, is how to combine the two classifiers? I like to know the standard algorithm to do that in an unsupervised way.

I tried to combine the two features into one feature (after normalization) but the HOG dominates the results. Even if I weighted the combined feature, results are worse than either of the two.

The good results I reach till now is to (cascade) the two classifiers, by running the color first to increase the possibilities then run the HOG (with a threshold a little bit higher than that used with HOG alone). I googled the topic but I don't have enough knowledge about classification to find the standard methods.

Thanks for help

Comment: Have you tried combining the two features with multiplication? This shouldn't suffer from amplitude issues you describe. I'm not particularly familiar with visual tracking, but some speech tracking algorithms use this to combine spatial likelihood functions from multiple sensors, so there may be some justification for this approach.

Comment: @Wakjah: that sounds like a good approach. I'd +1 it if you were to provide it as an answer.

Comment: @wakjah: if the color feature vector is 2x1 and the HOG is 81x1, what you suggest exactly for multiplication? Thanks

Comment: @MohamedHasan: I think he means that you calculate the distances f-f and HOG-HOG, and multiply them for a combined distance measure.

Comment: @Jonas: I haven't provided this as an answer because I'm not familiar with the form of those feature vectors, so I can't give a tractable example. Aside from that, I think this kind of question might be more suited to dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Mohamed Hasan  are you still stuck with this?  I assume your classifiers are something like if x is greater than a threshold obtained from feature 1, x will be classified as label 1, OR , if x is greater than a threshold obtained from feature 2, you then classify x as label 2? 


What i think you can do is to express it in the form for a energy minimization function (then you can use graphcut to solve, in this case, the result should contain the set of classification results with lowest error rates(in your case, lower your FN & FP)